# Java get json from Rest API Jira with SSO

Tags: java, json, rest, url, jira

I want to get data from our Jira API Rest. There is SSO, I'm automatically login with my Windows user.

When I call the homepage (https://jira.f.bbg/rest/api/2/search?jql) :
- With my java code : {"startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":0,"issues":[]}
- With my browser in private nav : {"startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":0,"issues":[]}
- With my browser : I got data I want from the api

When I call the API rest with parameter (https://jira.f.bbg/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PARE2) :
- With my java code : java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400
- With browser in private nav : {"errorMessages":["La valeur 'PARE2' n'existe pas pour le champ 'project'."],"errors":{}}
- With my browser : I got data I want from the api

I tried a lot of stuff, got SSL problem at the beginning, I use a jks and now it's ok. I don't really understand why I can't get data, and why I have error 400 when I had parameter to the url :(

```
  public String recuperer(String adresse) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(adresse);

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(SecuriteHelper.getSslContext().getSocketFactory());
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
  sb.append(line);
}

return sb.toString();
```

}

Comment: The errorMessage translates to English as - `PARE2` value does not exist for the field `project`. I think `console.log` from browser will give you better insights.

Comment: PARE2 is the name of my Jira project, I think I got this message because I'm not logged, then I havn't access to console.log file :(

Comment: The error you are getting is `400` that means what you are trying to access is not present on the server. And some error might have  been logged in your browser logs. If you can share that, we would have a clearer view.

Comment: I call it by my java code, not my browser.